# Javascript added form element not available via $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am using radio buttons in a form to hide/show a member id field in a contact form. Problem is when javascript changes the hidden id field included in html which is set to a value of "None", the field is no longer available via post, even if javascript changes it back to the original when the no radio box is checked. Please help, I am new to javascript, thanks.

Relevant Form Code:

```
echo '<tr><td>IVAO Member:</td><td><input type="radio" name="ivao" value="yes" onchange="ivaoVID()">Yes | <input type="radio" name="ivao" value="no" onchange="ivaoVID()" checked>No</td></tr>';
echo '<tr id="ivaovid"><input type="hidden" name="vid" id="vid" value="None"></tr>';
```

Javascript:

```
function ivaoVID() {
    var selected = document.getElementsByName("ivao");
    var row = document.getElementById("ivaovid");
    for(i = 0; i <selected.length; i++) {
        if (selected[i].checked == true) {
            if (selected[i].value == "yes") {
                row.innerHTML = "<td>IVAO VID:</td><td><input type='text' name='vid' id='vid'></td>";
            } else {
                row.innerHTML ="<input type='hidden' name='vid' id='vid' value='None'>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Action php file:

```
public function submit(){
    $model = new contactModel;
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name']:$this->registry->getData('fname').' '.$this->registry->getData('lname');
    $vid = isset($_POST['vid']) ? $_POST['vid']:$this->registry->getData('vid');
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']:$this->registry->getData('email');
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    echo $name . '<br> ' . $vid . '<br>' . $email . '<br>' . $message;
}
```

Comment: You're missing `<td>` around the elements of the `ivaovid` row.

Comment: Made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmodda27/) using your example and it seems to post fine.

Comment: The <td>'s shouldn't matter since it's a hidden input anyways, but I added them in. As for the fiddle you made that confuses me. I have no idea why mine isn't working, I'll have another look right now and hopefully come up with something. Thanks for the input guys :-)

Comment: If I try to echo $_POST['vid'] instead of using the isset(), I get an indefined index, however the js did in fact add the form field and I did fill it out and it is named and given an id. This is really weird

Comment: @divinecomedian Check out the demo at aaron-schpitzer.ca/en/contact and you'll notice that if you use google chrome's inspect element on the js added text field it is named and id'ed but however on the submit page it gives the undefined index. I am completely stumped and need a break. I'll take another look in an hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwriting the HTML like that messes up the form for some reason. No idea why exactly, but I see the same thing in both Chrome and IE.

If you go into the console and enter:

```
document.forms[0].vid
```

When you do it before changing the radio button you get a result, and when you do it after you get "undefined". The especially weird thing about it is that if you enter this in the console:

```
document.getElementById("vid")
```

You get a result in both cases.

One possible alternative would be to hide and show the "vid" text input instead of trying to overwrite it with a hidden input. To do that, you would change your PHP to write the text input version of the "ivaovid" row, then change your JavaScript to this:

```
function ivaoVID() {
    var selected = document.getElementsByName("ivao");
    var row = document.getElementById("ivaovid");
    var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
    for(i = 0; i <selected.length; i++) {
        if (selected[i].checked == true) {
            if (selected[i].value == "yes") {
                row.style.display = "";
                vid.value = "";
            } else {
                row.style.display = "none";
                vid.value = "None";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to hide and show the text input without modifying the value and ignore the value in your PHP post handler depending on the value of `$_POST['ivao']`.

Comment: It works! Here's the php line for anyone else who has this problem:echo '<tr id="ivaovid" style="display:none;"><td>IVAO VID:</td><td><input type="text" name="vid" id="vid" value="None"<td></tr>';